# SpookyJSで、CasperJS側にundefinedな変数を渡せない

Tags: javascript, casperjs, coffeescript

- casperjs@1.1.0-beta3
- spooky@0.2.5

を使って、スクリプトに渡したコマンドラインオプションをCasperJSの`then`コールバック内で使おうとしています。他の変数はちゃんとCasperJS内から見えるのですが、`undefined`な変数はどこかで消えてしまうのか、そんな変数はないよ ("Can't find variable") と言われてしまいます。

誰が勝手に消しているのでしょうか。また、どうすれば回避できるでしょうか。

```
Spooky = require 'spooky'

spooky = new Spooky
  child:
    command: './node_modules/casperjs/bin/casperjs'
  casper:
    logLevel: 'info'
    verbose: false
, (err) ->
  if err
    e = new Error 'Failed to initialize SpookyJS'
    e.details = err
    throw e

  spooky.on 'error', (e, stack) ->
    console.error(e)
    if (stack)
      console.log(stack)

  spooky.on 'console', (log) ->
    if (log.lastIndexOf('Unsafe JavaScript attempt', 0) == 0)
      return
    console.log(log)

  spooky.start 'http://example.com'
  spooky.then [{
    foo: 'bar'
    hello: undefined
  }, ->
    @echo foo
    @echo hello
  ]
  spooky.run()
```

出力:

```
$ coffee hello.coffee
bar
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: hello
[ { file: '', line: 5, function: '' },
  { file: '/path/to/node_modules/casperjs/modules/casper.js',
    line: 1553,
    function: 'runStep' },
  { file: '/path/to/node_modules/casperjs/modules/casper.js',
    line: 399,
    function: 'checkStep' } ]
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: hello
  /path/to:5
  /path/to/node_modules/casperjs/modules/casper.js:1553 in runStep
  /path/to/node_modules/casperjs/modules/casper.js:399 in checkStep
{ [Error: Child terminated with non-zero exit code 1] details: { code: 1, signal: null } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`undefined`な値が消えてしまうのは、[JSON](http://www.json.org/)で許容されていないためです: SpookyJSとCasperJS間の通信は、[JSON.stringifyでデータを渡す](https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS/blob/v0.2.5/lib/spooky.js#L129)ようになっています。

JSONで許容される値は、`string` `number` `object` `array` `true` `false` `null` のみです。

`undefined`になる可能性がある変数は、事前にチェックして`null`や`false`に強制変換することで回避できます。

```
hello = hello || false
```

もしくは一般化して:

```
var context = {foo: 'bar', hello: undefined};
for (var key in context) {
  if (typeof context[key] === 'undefined') {
    context[key] = false;
  }
}
```

```js
var context = {foo: 'bar', hello: undefined};

for (var key in context) {
  if (typeof context[key] === 'undefined') {
      context[key] = false;
  }
}

$('#console').text(JSON.stringify(context));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="console"></div>
```

Comment: `or` を `||` に修正。 `hello = None or "hell no"` は Python かと。

Comment: ありがとうございます。coffeescriptで書いていたのをコピペしてしまいました。汎用的な例の方がよいですね。